# Partition free space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS along with my Windows 10. I have already allocated a 40GB partition from Windows. Now, running the installation via my flash drive, I got stuck at setting manual partition which shows all available partition but my "free space" was only 1mb whereas I have 100GB free. Am I missing something here?

[image: screenshot of gparted showing partitions]

Comment: When you say you allocated space from Windows, did you also format it? What is sda5, the 37748MB ext4 partition?

Answer (score 0):

“free space” means the space not allocated to any partitions. It does not indicate the free space inside any partitions whatsoever. You should find the 40GB partition and format that.